# Can't start 'The Fate of the Skaal' quest

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dragonborn

Trying to start *The Fate of the Skaal* but Frea and her dad won't let me. I finished *The Temple of Miraak* a while ago (about 20 levels ago) so I can't reload the save. I am playing on the PS3.

I've tried rereading the black books and revisiting the temple to no avail.

Comment: Have you gone to Apocrypha?

Comment: I've gone through all but the last book.

Comment: If I remember correctly, you have to go through the entire thing and then a cutscene will occur and Frea will suggest going to the Skaal village. After that, just follow her, and you should be able to start it. Let me know if this works. If it does, I'll make it an answer for you to accept.

Comment: I finished that part, she's in the Skaal village, I don't think I went with her when I finished it originally.

Comment: Have you activated the wind stone yet by any chance? If not try going unlocking it and going back to the village.

Comment: I'll give it a try.

Comment: Let me know if it works, alternatively if that doesn't, you could try reopening the exit passage.

Comment: Doesn't seem to have worked.

Comment: I cannot find any other proposed solutions to the bug. There are a lot of people who have had this bug, and the general consensus is you are going to have to load an older save to finish it.

Answer (score 3):

It appears after extensive research, that there are two possible solutions, but if they don't work, the only way to fix is loading an older save. The two solutions are

1. Checking to see if the wind stone is unlocked, if not go visit it then return to the village.
2. Reopen the exit passage from the temple and then return to the village.

Note, you should check to make sure you have completed all parts of Temple of Miraak.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind just redoing Solstheim and restarting the dragonborn quest line, there is a solution to this. What you need to do is make a save of your current game somewhere other than in solstheim probably. Then uninstall the dragonborn dlc from your system. Then load that save you just created in skyrim. It will give you a warning that the save contains data from an add-on that has been removed, but all it should do is remove the quests and any items that are exclusive to the dragonborn dlc, which is fine cuz youll do it again anyways. Then after youve loaded into that game and made sure that everything from the dlc is gone, create another save file at that same point so that the game will load that file as one without the dlc at all. Then reinstall the dragonborn dlc and load that save file and just redo the whole dragonborn quest line starting with the cultists approaching you randomly. Make sure you make a separate save after the dlc is uninstalled cuz if you dont and just reinstall it and use the same file, i dont think anything will be different cuz that file will still contain the data for the dragonborn dlc. You still have to redo solstheim and the dragonborn quest line but its better than comoletely starting over or reloading a save from way back.

I had the same problem where I think I fast traveled instead of just following Frea. And, at the time I didn't realize that something went wrong so I just kept on playing the game. So I did a bunch of other things and got to level 40 before realizing I was missing a bunch of the dragonborn quest line. So I wouldve had to revert back to a save a long time ago when I was only level 30 to fix the quest line. Wouldve been a pain to do aalll that crap again. Its much easier to just redo solstheim than like half of skyrim lol.